# Unix - count unique IP addresses, sort them by most frequent and also sort them by IP when number of repetitions is same

Tags: bash, sort, uniq

I have a list of IP addresses in file:

```
  72.204.55.250
  72.204.55.250
  72.204.55.250
  72.204.55.250
  72.204.55.250
  96.41.51.202
  208.115.113.91
  178.137.94.166
  178.137.94.166
  208.115.113.91
  96.41.51.202
  141.8.143.179
  141.8.143.179
```

Now I am going to sort them and call `uniq -c` service and I get:

```
  2  141.8.143.179
  2  178.137.94.166
  2  208.115.113.91
  5  72.204.55.250
  2  96.41.51.202
```

Now I will sort them by most frequent (`sort -rn`) but my problem is to also sort them by IP address when the number of repetitions is same in descending order. I've found a sort command for only IP address which works:

```
sort -rn -t . -k1,1 -k2,2 -k 3,3 -k4,4
```

but as I mentioned it above, I don't know how to combine it with first column (number of repetitions) to get these expected results:

```
  5  72.204.55.250
  2  208.115.113.91
  2  178.137.94.166
  2  141.8.143.179
  2  96.41.51.202
```

How can I achieve that? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Well you can use this to get the quantity sorted in the correct order, but the ip addresses themselves will be in reverse order: `sort -rn <file> | uniq -c`

Comment: Exactly and there is the problem - I need them both in the same order.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your sort can do a *stable sort*, e.g. GNU sort with the `-s` or `--stable` option, lines with fields unrelated to the sort keys will not be sorted by those fields when there are ties, but will stay in their same relative positions.

```
$ sort -n -t. -k1,1 -k2,2 -k3,3 -k4,4 | uniq -c | sort -n -r -s
  5 72.204.55.250
  2 96.41.51.202
  2 141.8.143.179
  2 178.137.94.166
  2 208.115.113.91
```

Comment: @don_crissti yes it is needed, some IP addresses are not sorted correctly. This is a correct answer for me, just when you want to sort IP addresses in descending order too, just add -r in first sort. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

While you *can* do this with command line tools, here is a way to do it quickly if you have access to any Postgres database (just for fun):

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ cat ips.txt 
72.204.55.250
72.204.55.250
72.204.55.250
72.204.55.250
72.204.55.250
96.41.51.202
208.115.113.91
178.137.94.166
178.137.94.166
208.115.113.91
96.41.51.202
141.8.143.179
141.8.143.179
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ psql
Expanded display is used automatically.
psql (9.3.15)
Type "help" for help.

vagrant=# create temp table ips (ipaddress inet);
CREATE TABLE
vagrant=# \copy ips from ips.txt
vagrant=# select count(*), ipaddress
vagrant-# from ips
vagrant-# group by ipaddress
vagrant-# order by count desc, ipaddress
vagrant-# ;
 count |   ipaddress    
-------+----------------
     5 | 72.204.55.250
     2 | 96.41.51.202
     2 | 141.8.143.179
     2 | 178.137.94.166
     2 | 208.115.113.91
(5 rows)

vagrant=# \q
[vagrant@localhost ~]$
```

I actually have a sandbox Postgres instance on a Vagrant machine for this sort of action.  Handy.

Note the proper sorting by IP address, rather than alphabetical sorting.  That's due to using the Postgres data type for IP addresses, "inet."

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be way simpler than the other solutions posted here.

With IP addresses like this:

```
72.204.55.250
72.204.55.250
96.41.51.202
208.115.113.91
178.137.94.166
```

You can just do this: 
`$ sort file | uniq -c | sort -n -r -k1,1`

### Explaination:

1. first we sort the file (uniq won't work without this)
2. then we count the number of occurances for each IP in our list
3. Then we sort again, by the counts

   - `-n` - treat values as numeric
   - `-r` - reversse the order to be highest count first
   - `-k1` - sort by first column (more options are available, but thats all we need here)